# Why is this div not breaking to the next line?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple inner/outer div problem where it's probably easier to explain through pictures. Here is my issue:

[image]

The comment "This is a witty comment." is not breaking down underneath the other 2 labels. Here is my HTML:

```
                <div class="commentOuter">
                    <div class="commentAuthor">someauthor</div>
                    <div class="commentDate">17 minutes ago</div>
                    <div class="commentText"><span>This is a witty comment.</span></div>
                </div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.commentOuter
{
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.commentAuthor
{
    float: left;
    font-size: smaller;
    color: #68a5d9;
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
}

.commentDate
{
    float: left;
    font-size: smaller;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: #AAA;
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
}

.commentText
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I don't understand that when I highlight the element in the dev tools, the div is not showing to be underneath the labels, as seen in this pic:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I remove the <span> tag and leave it as the <div> text, same issue.

Comment: Float left on commentDate means that next one may come to it's right.

Comment: You should add `clear: both;` on `.commentText`

Comment: @AntoineB Well that's caused the text to snap underneath now, but the commentOuter isn't resizing to the content. http://i.imgur.com/NhbTE4L.png

Comment: Remove the height from `.outerComment`, or put `min-height: 20px;` instead.

Comment: Bah! I limited the height of the outer didn't I >< . Stupid me, thanks @AntoineB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you floated the previous 2 elements. If you need to move it below. Use a clear:

```
.commentText
{
   clear:both;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}
```

You also have to remove the specified `height` for the `.outerComment` element.

Just because it's not floated, doesn't mean it won't be next to other elements.

See more here: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/